# Can I write a text on UHF RFID tag with RC522 module?

Tags: tags, compatibility, rfid, mifare, contactless-smartcard

I want to write a text on a UHF RFID tag. Can I write with the RC522 module?
What software is appropriate for this work?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. The RC522 module can only interact with ISO/IEC 14443 Type A (13.56 MHz HF RFID) contactless tags and smartcards. Consequently, you can neither read nor write any UHF RFID tags with it.